# Is there something wrong with my jQuery syntax?

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I'm trying to use jQuery to add an onclick attribute to links that contain a certain domain in the href. There are no errors, but for some reason it's not working

Note: the `[% property_info.Website %]` is a template system tag, and is text by the time it reaches the browser.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var hotelWebsite = "[% property_info.Website %]";
    $('a[href*="'+hotelWebsite+'"]').attr('onclick', 'pageTracker._link(this.href); return false;');
});
```

Comment: did you try to debug the value of `hotelWebsite` with Firebug?

Comment: Why aren't you binding events using the proper jQuery [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method?

Comment: return:false is not valid javascript

Comment: @JMax, Yes hotelWebsite does contain the string I expect in Firebug.

Comment: @Matt... what? I'm not using any event other than load.  Does the $(docuement).ready(function()   no longer do that for me?  Maybe you could provide an example?

Comment: I think @Ben was suggesting that `.attr('onclick'...` should be `.on('click', function()...`

Answer (score 7):

use `return false;` instead of `return:false;`

I changed your code below, try it.

```
$(function() {
    var hotelWebsite = "[% property_info.Website %]";
    $('a[href*="'+hotelWebsite+'"]').click(function() {
        pageTracker._link(this.href); 
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Comment: It's very difficult to verify if that actually works, because the pageTracker._link() method is sent to Google Analytics. I though about doing it this way too, but wanted to be strict and follow the Google Analytics documentation, and they say to use onclick attributes.  In my own tests I changed `onclick` with `data-test` and it worked.  So maybe there's a strange limitation that jquery imposes that does not allow an onchange attribute to be added.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out jQuery doesn't like `onclick` as an attribute, but takes `onClick` just fine. Once I camel cased it, it started working.